# Size check on future list in Scala

Tags: list, scala, future

I have a method which return `Future[List[Employee]]`. I want to check the list size for various purpose. I am not able to call `size` on list and I think its because its in `Future`. Any suggestion?

```
val employees: Future[List[Employee]] = companyService.findEmployeesWorkingOn(someDate) 
employees match {
  case emp if(emp.size == 1) => Logger.info("Only one employee working")
  case emp if(emp.size == 0) => Logger.info("No one working")
  case _ => Logger.info("Multiple employees working")
}
```

Comment: try flatMapping on the `Future`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "wait" for the future to happen or not. You can use `map` to map the `Future[List[Employee]]` to a `Future[Int]` and use the `onSuccess` callback.

```
val sizeFuture = employees.map(_.size) // returns a Future[Int]
sizeFuture onSuccess {
  case size:Int => println(size) // do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for comprehension which desugars to a `flatMap`,

```
for ( e <- employees ) yield e.size match {...}
```

Here list `e` is matched only if the future succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

No need to check the size for your use case:

```
val employees: Future[List[Employee]] = …
val result = employees map {
  case Nil => "no employees"
  case List(e) => "one employee"
  case es => "multiple employees"
}
```